# Selecting range with RegExp

Tags: regex, syntax, vbscript

I'll explain what I'm after with example code. My function `GetDox` looks close but it's still incomplete. Here is a testing code.

```
'test begin...
'<dox>
'  <member type="Public Sub" name="Increment" return="void">
'    <param type="Integer" name="nBase" out="true" />
'    <param type="Integer" name="nStep" out="false" />
'    <purpose>
'      purpose here...
'    </purpose>
'  </member>
'  <member ... />
'</dox>
'other comments here...
Public Sub Increment(nBase, nStep) 'some example content
    nBase = nBase + nStep
End Sub
'<Unwonted_Item />

Dim source  'reading the same file just for simplification
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With .OpenTextFile(WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, False)
        source = .ReadAll
    End With
End With
result = GetDox(source)
WScript.Echo result  'display our result

Function GetDox(sCode)  'unfinished function
    Dim regEx, Match, Matches, mVal, sEnd
    sEnd = "</dox>" & vbNewLine
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "('<dox>\n|'\s*<.*)" 'my ugly pattern
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(sCode)
    For Each Match In Matches
        mVal = Match.Value
        mVal = Replace(mVal, vbCr, vbNewLine)
        mVal = Right(mVal, Len(mVal) - 1)
        GetDox = GetDox & mVal
        If mVal = sEnd Then Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

This is what I get:

```
<dox>
  <member type="Public Sub" name="Increment" return="void">
    <param type="Integer" name="nBase" out="true" />
    <param type="Integer" name="nStep" out="false" />
    <purpose>
    </purpose>
  </member>
  <member ... />
</dox>
```

And this is what I need:

```
<dox>
  <member type="Public Sub" name="Increment" return="void">
    <param type="Integer" name="nBase" out="true" />
    <param type="Integer" name="nStep" out="false" />
    <purpose>
      purpose here...
    </purpose>
  </member>
  <member ... />
</dox>
```

The line with "purpose here..." missing, and I know that the whole `RegExp.Pattern` syntax is weak. I just want to select whole content that start with `<dox>` and end with `</dox>` including everything within as well, but I'm stuck on the pattern syntax.

**P.S.**  With so excellent help (thanks to all), this is my working function now:

```
Function GetDox(sCode)
    GetDox = vbNullString
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern    = "<dox>[\s\S]*?</dox>"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global     = False
        With .Execute(sCode)
            If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function
            GetDox  = .Item(0).Value
        End With
        .Pattern    = "^'"
        .Global     = True
        .Multiline  = True
        GetDox = .Replace(GetDox, "")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Why do you use regular expressions instead of XPath etc. ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I extract a XML binded in .VBS file as comment, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first remove the leading single quotes:

```
regEx.Pattern = "^'"
regEx.Global  = True
sCode = regEx.Replace(sCode, "")
```

Then extract the XML text:

```
regEx.Pattern = "<dox>[\s\S]*?</dox>"
regEx.Global  = False
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
Set m = regEx.Execute(sCode)
If m.Count > 0 Then GetDox = m(0).Value
```

After that you should read the XML into a [DOM tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756987) for further processing:

```
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.loadXML result
```

If your XML is in a separate file, you should directly load the XML from the file and extract the nodes with an [XPath](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.2/expressions.html) expression, as @FrankSchmitt suggested in his comment.

```
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load "C:\path\to\your.xml"

Set nodes = xml.selectNodes("//dox")
```

XML isn't line-oriented and shouldn't be parsed as if it were. Things are likely to break in interesting ways if you don't handle it properly.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed answer! I set `.Multiline = True` before call `.Replace` to remove single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To repair your code you could use this regex: `('<dox>\n|'\s*[\S \t]*)` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aE4mE1)

Another way to do it would be to get everything you need first with `<dox>[\s\S]+?<\/dox>` then apply a replace over it:
Search: `^'` and replace with nothing

or, to clear the leading whitespace:
Search: `^'\s*` and replace with nothing [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cY8rI7)